# Microservices Architectural Design

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, microservices

I have been reading tutorials and codes on microservices, mostly, in Java (I know microservice is independent of language).

But, I'm still confused how to design microservices.

For example, in a sale application, at least, it has the following resources:

- products
- customers
- orders

Should I create a project for each resource? Let's say: **product-service**, **customer-service**, and **order-service**. If I were to use Spring Boot, these would have respective port number to run on - 8080, 8081, 8082.

How about the domain model classes - Customer, Product, Order? Should I create another project and import it to the three projects?

Please enlighten me. Add more relevant topics if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microservices granularity is a subject of many studies. some practical experience shows dividing microservices based on domain context (DDD practices) can be effective. like what you did in your example however deciding on granularity of services depends on many other things.
some factor to be considered can be :

- size/number of development team.
- hardware/resource consumption
- service location distribution
- number of service communication to handle a request
- service re-usability ( to avoid repetitive work)
- performance
- etc

google about service granularity principle. there are many other factor to consider.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Does my example require greater amount/number/any measurements of the factors you've enumerated, or just the basic ones?

Comment: look at this https://github.com/ewolff/microservice a fully example of microservices architecture. It contains catalog-service, customer-service, and order-service like your example.

Comment: and this for explanation http://meuslivros.github.io/microservices-flexible-software-architectures/text/part0019.html

Comment: Thanks for the links.